# Detect touch in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need to stop autorotatation, if user touches to photo slider.
I use UITapGestureRecognizer to detect touch at UICollectionView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapCollectionView(_:)))
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

func tapCollectionView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("touch")
    }
```

It works when I tap on collection view.
But when I'm touching collection view and scrolling this collection view, my function 'tapCollectionView' is not called.

Comment: that isn't a tap, that's a swipe. That's why it won't detect it. To achieve that, you can add a **UIScrollGestureRecognizer**, too

Comment: Provided your `UICollectionView's` *contentSize* is more than the `UICollectionView` size, you could just use various delegate functions that `UICollectionView` offers without having to add a `UITapGesture` or `UISwipeGesture`.

Comment: I need to stop autorotatation, if user touches to photo slider. I can't use "scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation" because this can be autorotation and not user touches

Comment: Swift 3 doesn't contain **UIScrollGestureRecognizer**

Answer (score -2):

It helped me:

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

// Stop your timer  here

        timer?.invalidate() 
    }
}
```